# C++0x lambda + boost::function trouble

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I have a problem with lambdas in MSVC2010.

It is successful compiled:

```
auto f1 = []() { };
boost::function<void()> a = f1;
```

But it brings an error C2440:

```
auto f2 = []()
{
    auto f3 = []() { };
    boost::function<void()> b = f3;
};
```

Error C2440:

```
'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'boost::function<Signature>'
    with
    [
        Signature=void (void)
    ]
    No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Why? Does it work in GCC4.6?

Comment: Why are you using boost::function instead of std::function?

Comment: Because dependent libraries of my project use boost::function. Does it  work with std::function?

Comment: I tested your code with vc10 but used `std::function` instead. It compiles fine. So, does the code with clang 3.2 and gcc 4.6.2. I don't have the boost libraries handy so I can't comment on your exact problem. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bug in MSVC (the error message seems very suspicious). It works in GCC 4.7.

Comment: decltype(f3) is ok. it isn't 'int', it is 'lambda0'.